# Different display of components in navigators

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8

My problem consist of displaying components in forms. First I m working on a JSF and facelet application. In one of my pages I put a inputText with a fixed width but when I execute the project in Chrome and IE navigators I have a different display mostly in component width.

This is the part of code: `<h:inputText style=" width : 600px;" value="#{MyBean.Name}" />`

component width in chrome :602px

component width in IE : 604px

Can anyOne help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achraf,

Often this problem has to do with `padding` or lack thereof. IE handles `padding` relative to `width` differently than most of the other browsers. One adds the `padding` to the `width`, while some others track `padding` and `width` separately. This inconsistency among browsers is so prevalent that I commonly start my CSS with `body * {padding:0;}` and override in specific styles as needed.

Additionally, the less style you specify, the more control the browser (or User Agent) has over the style of rules that are not specified. This means that these browsers with the inconsistent widths are probably adding `padding` to the `<input>` as they deem necessary. Try adding `padding:0` to your `style` attribute for your `<input>`. This will force the issue and may require a little tweaking but should ultimately solve your problem.

Hope this helps,
FuzzicalLogic